# SSH inside perl script hangs

Tags: linux, perl, ssh

I am trying to execute the following command using perl script :

```
my $sum = `$sudo $ssh $server netstat -Aan | /bin/grep 1158 | /bin/egrep '@IP[0]' | wc -l`;
```

Where $sudo = full path to sudo command , same for $ssh , $server = the file server that I want to pull the data from , and @Ip[0] = ip address.

When I run the exact command from the shell (not as a script) I get the required result (which is an integer number). However , when I run the script it just gets hangs when it reaches to that point.

I cant see anything wrong with the syntax , I am using back ticks to save the returned output , could you please assist?

Comment: Please paste the command to you are executing from shell.

Comment: You probably have to change `@IP[0]` to `$IP[0]`.

Comment: Tried your suggestion to change from @IP[0] to $IP[0] and issue persists.

Comment: @user3586606: Remove single quotes or escape them with \.

Comment: @DineshPundkar , I cant paste the command online , but believe me it is working.

Comment: Hi , @ChankeyPathak , thanks for the suggestion , but this didnt not solve the problem .  I escaped it that way:       \'@IP[0]\'

Comment: Please print output of the following: `my $command = qq{$sudo $ssh $server netstat -Aan | /bin/grep 1158 | /bin/egrep $IP[0] | wc -l}; print $command;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ssh perl script not running](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36806520/ssh-perl-script-not-running)